# How to let animating view stay at the current position when [layer removeAllAnimations] called

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

If there are two animations happens in sequence, I would like to remove the first animation, and start the second animation from the current position. I used [layer removeAllAnimations] to cancel the first animation before adding the second animation to the layer, the layer always goes back to the initial position. I know it's the default action of removeAllAnimations, but I would like to know if there's any way you can set the layer to stay the current position.
     Thank you very much.

Update -- 
 I got this done by getting the presentationLayer position and assign it to the model layer position. And I also used 
    - (void)animationDidStop:(UIAnimation*)animation finished:(BOOL)flag;
to check if the animation finishes.

Comment: You don't have to call `removeAllAnimations` (if you're affraid of memory leak). Anyway: `animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;` usually do the trick.

Comment: Thank you rokjarc. Yes, you are right, but what I want to do is cancel the first animation before it finishes and start the second one. I get this done by getting the presentationLayer position and assign it to the model layer position. After that, I also modify animationDidStop delegate method to check if the animation did stop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use: myView.frame = [[myView.layer presentationLayer] frame]